# hash table - how often is the hash calculated for a given key?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I was asked this during an interview. My immediate answer was for every read and write. The interviewer then asked, "Are you sure the hash isn't cached in the table somewhere?"

This made me second guess myself. In the end, I stuck to my original answer, but out of curiosity, I figured I'd as the question here.

Also note that this interview was for a JavaScript position but the question wasn't necessarily specific to JavaScript.

So, in general, is a key's hash computed once or for every read/write? What about specific to JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it depends on the implementation, and even if you ask about JS there are several implementations (V8, SpiderMonkey, MSFT etc.).

It also should depend on the application. If your application is one that more frequently use the last item put into the hashtable then it should make sense to somehow cache the hash. In some cases this would be preferable.

I guess the interviewer just tried to see how you handle second-guessing...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the hash table and the key types, and on whether we're talking about the key used to read/write or the keys already in the table. The hash values of the former can and sometimes is cached in the object (example: strings in Python). The hash values of the latter can and sometimes are cached in the table - instead of key, value pairs you store hash, key, value triples.

In both cases, the decision depends on the kind of keys: Are they large and expensive to hash? Is it worth the extra space and memory traffic? For example, it's probably a clear win for strings larger than a couple dozen characters, and probably useless or harmful for 2D points. Also note that the hash values can be used to avoid comparisons, which *might* be useful but doesn't seem as important.